# ArrayList or Map? Also help on how to store the children

Tags: java, arraylist, dictionary

I'm working on a project that has two classes. One that creates a class that defines a Person and another called FamilyInfo that creates either an ArrayList or Map. FamilyInfo reads in a Scanner that is from a text file of names and their mother father relationships.

The names.txt file first has a list of all the names. Then lists a name, the mother, then the father.
Example:

> Henry VII
>  Arthur
>  Elizabeth of York
>  etc
>  etc
>  ...
>   END OF NAMES, CHILD/MOTHER/FATHER records follow:
>   -
>  Arthur
>  Elizabeth of York
>  Henry VII
>   -
>  Henry VIII
>  Elizabeth of York
>  Henry VII
>   -
>  etc
>  etc

This is my Person class so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String mother;
    private String father;
    private ArrayList<String> kids;

    public Person(String name, String mother, String father) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
    }

    public Person(String name, String mother, String father, ArrayList<String> kids) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mother = mother;
        this.father = father;
        this.kids = kids;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getMother() {
        return mother;
    }

    public String getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public String nthKid(int i) {
        return kids.get(i);
    }

    public int numKids() {
        return kids.size();
    }
}
```

This is what I have for FamilyInfo:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FamilyInfo {

    private Map<String, Person> personMap;

    public FamilyInfo() {
        personMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();
    }

    public void read(Scanner input) {
        ArrayList<String> kids = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = input.nextLine();
            if(name.equals("-")) {
                continue;
            }
            if(personMap.containsKey(name)) {
                String mother = input.nextLine();
                String father = input.nextLine();

                personMap.put(name, new Person(name, mother, father));
            } else {
                personMap.put(name, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public Person getPerson(String names) {
        return personMap.get(names);
    }
}
```

The issue that I have is figuring out how to store the kids. I have it passing an ArrayList of them but I have no idea how to get them and pass it. Also wondering if using a map is the best way to go about this or should I maybe change it to an ArrayList? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you would need to consider creating mother, father and kids of type Person itself rather than considering just their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I see what you want to do. Consider the following refactoring:

First make your instance variables in the Person class of type Person:

```
private String name;
private Person mother;
private Person father;
private ArrayList<Person> kids = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Then remove the constructors add this one:

```
public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

but in addition to this, have setters to set the mother and father, and a way to add kids to the list of kids:

```
public void setMother(Person mother) {
    this.mother = mother;
}

public void getFather(Person father) {
    this.father = father;
}

public void addKid(Person kid) {
    this.kids.add(kid);
}
```

---

Now moving on to the FamilyInfo class, using a map is good, because you want to be able to look up the people in the database quickly. The real magic happens in the while loop:

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {
    String name = input.nextLine();
    if(name.equals("-")) {
        continue;
    }
    if(personMap.containsKey(name)) {
        // find the people
        Person mother = personMap.get(input.nextLine());
        Person father = personMap.get(input.nextLine());
        Person kid = personMap.get(name);

        // link them up
        kid.setMother(mother);
        kid.setFather(father);
        mother.addKid(kid);
        father.addKid(kid);
    } else {
        personMap.put(name, new Person(name)); // create the people objects from the initial list
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think to use setters and this has definitely helped me to get on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you expected to use these classes, or are they of your own making?

In your model, you have described a person. A person has parents (mother, father), but parents are people too - you should probably model them as such.

So we can say a person has one father and one mother, each parent can have 1 or more children. Parents know their children and children know their parents - this should tell you how to model the relationships. This would make the `FamilyInfo` redundant as each person would manage it's own relationships.

You should make the process of reading the data and creating the objects external to the model.

@user2864740 comment is still valid and you will need to understand the difference